# sqlalchemy @hybrid_property v @property, @hybrid_method v @classmethod

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, properties, python-decorators

I have a Model (which I'm using as an abstract base class), that has some common methods and properties.

SQLAlchemy allows creating properties and methods with `@hybrid_property` and `@hybrid_method`, but also the standard `@property`, `@classmethod`, `@staticmethod` decorators give me the results I'm after.

Are there any advantages and disadvantages using the SQLA decorators over the standard python decorators?

**When should I use, or shouldn't use, the SQLA decorators?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The hybrid provides for an expression that works at both the Python
> level as well as at the SQL expression level

Let's look at an example:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String(50))
    lastname = Column(String(50))

    @hybrid_property
    def fullname(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname

    @property
    def long_name(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname


session.add(User(firstname='Brendan', lastname='Simon'))
session.commit()
# error
# print(session.query(User).filter(User.long_name == 'Brendan Simon').first().id)
# works fine because @hybrid_property
print(session.query(User).filter(User.fullname == 'Brendan Simon').first().id)
```

Also you can customize `SQL expression` using [@fullname.expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property.expression).

**When should I use, or shouldn't use, the SQLA decorators?**

I think you will know when you need it. For example, you can use it for fast aliases:

```
class MetaData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'meta_data'
    system_field = Column(String(20))  # a lot of calculations and processing in different places
    # a lot of fields ...
```

One day in a few parts `system_field` was(or will be) renamed to `new_field`(doesn't matter why, who and when - just fact). You can do something like this as a quick solution:

```
@hybrid_property
def new_field(self):
    return self.system_field

@new_field.setter
def new_field(self, value: str):
    self.system_field = value

# data from somewhere...
# data = {'new_field': 'default', other fields...}
# will works fine + in other places will work as `system_field` with old sql queries
process_meta(MetaData(**{data}))
```

So this is really good feature, but if you are thinking about whether you need it or not, then you definitely don't need it.

Comment: Ok.  So in summary best approach is to uses standard python decorators, and then move to SQLA decorators when/if there is a need.  Presumably for filtering purposes.